# Is "taking him going away" a common fishing phrase?

Tags: terminology

Has anyone ever heard the phrase "taking him going away" used to describe the experience of hooking a fish ("him") while it is moving away from/in the opposite direction of the person fishing?

Comment: Related: _[Fishing terminology: What phrase describes a fish getting caught on the hook?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/14598/5822)_

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be more of a hunting phrase from these two [references](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22take%20him%20going%20away%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&ds=bo&sugexp=ldymls&pq=%22take%20him%20going%20away%22&xhr=t&q=%22take%20him%20going%20away%22&cp=6&pf=p&sclient=psy&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=%22take%20him%20going%20away%22&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=a58dd126b32ffd8&biw=1280&bih=705) I found:

[image]

[image]

I'm not familiar with this being adopted into fishing lingo—at least not in fly-fishing. Although there may be similar terms for the different ways a fish can take a fly. If a fish is hit by a hook and caught other than by its mouth, it is said to be *snagged*.

Answer (score 0):

I've not heard it exactly like that but I fully understand the meaning. When a fish takes bait there is a window of opportunity to strike to ensure a secure contact between hook and fish. That window of opportunity varies between fish and bait (and many other factors).

"Taking him going away", I would interpret as let the fish run and then strike. Another similar example would be - Let the carp head-off and strike when the float is under