# A word used to describe a fish trying to eat bait bit by bit

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

What is a word used to describe a fish that tries to eat bait with light continual biting? In other words, the fish tries to eat the bait bit by bit but never swallows the whole hook.

Comment: I'm not sure if this qualifies as a duplicate, but this question can be addressed by this answer: [Fishing terminology: What phrase describes a fish getting caught on the hook?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14598/fishing-terminology-what-phrase-describes-a-fish-getting-caught-on-the-hook)

Comment: It's not specific to fishing so I won't make it an answer, but look up **nibble**.

Comment: In spite of the title of the possible dupe, the answer says "

"Nibble" refers to a seemingly tentative attempt to take the hook and can be used as the event takes place or in later descriptions. Nibble is often used in a derogatory ( self-deprecating) fashion as in "I (he) caught 3 fish, but he (I) only had a couple of nibbles." This is most frequently used when "still fishing" (just letting the hook dangle instead of pulling it through the water) with "bait" (see below)."

Comment: Seconding @TaliesinMerlin's answer, it's nibble. You can see an example here: http://www.upnorthoutdoors.com/upnorth/fishstories/jerrycarlson/finicky.html

Comment: Yes, *nibble* is what immediately came to my mind upon reading the title, before even clicking on it.

Comment: Yea, 'nibble' is the correct word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To turn several good comments into an answer: [**nibble**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nibble).

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a** : to bite gently
>   **1 b** : to eat or chew in small bits

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a dictionary definition to your answer (with a link). This is generally a minimum that's required of good answers here. Feel free to modify my formatting if you wish (or use a different definition and link).

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking back to fishing trips with my grandpa. When he described this to us, and when we would talk about it with him or with each other, there are a few ways of expressing this concept that I can remember.

1) "He's nibbling at it."

OR

2) "He's picking at it."

OR

3) "He's trying to steal your worm."

I agree with the other comments and the answer by @Roger - "nibble" is probably the most-commonly-used word, but I wanted to add these alternatives. The second and third options - especially the third - seem to express all the nuances of

> tr[ying] to eat the bait bit by bit

a bit better than simply using, "He's nibbling at your worm." That's my feeling, anyway. Often, the comment with *nibbling* expressed an expectation that the fish would soon take a big bite and get caught. The comment with *stealing* expressed the idea that the fish knew that the worm was on a hook and was therefore trying to get all the meal he could without touching the hook. The comment with *picking* was somewhere in between.

By the way, it seemed that we always said something like, "He'll get greedy, eventually," after the preceding statements.

---

P.S. I guess all fishes were male until we gutted them and found out differently.